# history command in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, history

I can't delete the shell history in macOS Catalina. I use `rm ~/.bash_history`.

`history -c` all command fields. I need to delete the command history.

Comment: Which shell are you using, `bash`, `zsh` or something else? If unsure, run `ps -p $$` and look into the `CMD` column.

Answer (score 4):

Just do a

```
rm ~/.zsh_history
```

that clears the history. After that close the Terminal app. To check if the history was cleared run

```
history
```

in Terminal.

Comment: its works perfectly in Catalina

Answer (score 1):

- Close all terminal tabs and windows except one
- `rm ~/.bash_history`
- `history -c`
- Quit and restart Terminal

Comment: Try `rm ~/.zhistory`? ;-)

Comment: @klanomath Might be an option, once the OP clarifies which shell they use :-)

Comment: I thought Catalina defaulted to zsh...

Comment: @allan for new accounts only

Comment: @nohillside -  Ahhh...so used to doing clean installs and not upgrading that I miss those details.  Thx.